# Caesar substituion -function not returning results

Tags: python

I have the following python code which is supposed to use brute force to decrypt secret message. The encryption technique is Ceasarean subsitution i.e. every letter in the alphabet is moved by a certain number of places. My main function is supposed to return the decrypted message with the letters moved by all 26 possible number of places (I hope it makes sense but its basically like ROT13 but we don't know the number. It could be ROT13, ROT5, ROT20 etc.)

The problem is my main function doesn't print out the result from the caesarBreak function.

Thanks in advance!

```
import sys

def caesarBreak(cipheredMsg):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
    shift = 1
    plainText = ""

    for ch in cipheredMsg:
        idx = alphabet.find(ch) - shift
        plainText = plainText + alphabet[idx]
        shift = shift + 1
    return plainText

def main():

 print("We will now try to break the msg: 'we ovugpzghugpu lylz pungwyvnyhttpungshunahnl'\n\n")
    secretmsg = 'we ovugpzghugpu lylz pungwyvnyhttpungshunahnl'
    caesarBreak(secretmsg)

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you didn't ask your main function to print it.

`print(caesarBreak(secretmsg))`

it did return the result, if you find a place to store it then later you could print it out or do whatever you want with it.

```
result = caesarBreak(secretmsg)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks Yunkai! I thought the print was for both the string and function.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Yunkai Xiao, you have to use print() to print out your result.

```html
print(#your function here)
```

Also, there might be other error for you to check just a fyi.

Comment: Geez how could I not notice that?! Lol! Thanks!